# make Owl Carousel not to stop slide by slide on dragging

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm trying to make a smooth scrolling on Owl Carousel that does not move slide by slide. So it has smooth slide over slides on mobile devices. Currently it's scrolling two items by each drag and I want it to continue to next slide according to dragging speed like in Gallery applications.

This is my code:

```
$('.owl-carousel_slider_php').owlCarousel({
    loop:false,
    margin:10,
    Autoplay:true , 
     nav    : true,
     dots: false, 
     rtl:true, 
     slideBy:'page',
      slideSpeed: 100,
     pagination:false,
         slideTransition: 'linear',

     navText : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"],
   autoWidth:true,
   
})
```